# How to compare the installed RPM packages between two Linux hosts

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I am trying to do a failover test and need to ensure that the active and standby servers have the same configuration. So the list of installed RPM packages is one of the checks.

As a DIY workaround, I could call the command `yum list installed` on both servers and compare the screen outputs as text files. However, these Red Hat Enterprise Linux servers are under the corporate IT team's management. Instead of the official Red Hat repository, they refer to different satellite repositories depending on which data centers they locate. The difference in the source repository will become noises in the text diff later.

And I think there should be a more standard method than the DIY workaround above. So, I will highly appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to compare directly `rpm` files installed. The command to get the list is:

```
rpm -qа >server1.list
```

And having two lists you can print lines (RPM's) which are on first sever only:

```
comm -23 server1.list server2.list
```

and this to show packages existing only on server2:

```
comm -13 server1.list server2.list
```